# Is there any way to transpose columns into rows in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, postgresql-9.1

I would like to switch columns and rows in postgresql. Is there any way to do that considering that the date will keep increasing over time and therefore create more columns?

[image: current table]

Comment: The tablefunc extension has a pivot function, however you must specify them in the query, it cannot dynamically generate columns

Comment: Hi @Lucas thank you for your reply I'll check the tablefunc, too bad it can't generate columns dynamically

Comment: This sounds like something that should be done in the presentation layer, not in the database. What's the actual requirement to transpose your data?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+pivot)

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name says there's no way for a SELECT statement to do it dynamically. You can still do it using "dynamic SQL". Any ORM out there offers some kind of utility for this.

Comment: @Zack thanks for your comment! I finally did in the presentation layer. I was just curious to know if there was a way to do that in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Thanks for your reply @TheImpaler